# On the minimum eigenvalue of permutation matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boolean-algebra

It can be shown that the maximum eigenvalue of a row-stochastic matrix is $1$, adapting, e.g. [What are possible eigenvalues of a 0-1 (boolean) matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733362/what-are-possible-eigenvalues-of-a-0-1-boolean-matrix)

*A contrario* no general result holds regarding its minimum eigenvalue. But, ***is it still true that no general result holds if one adds the condition that the matrix, in addition to being row-stochastic, is a permutation matrix ?*** Also, note that only their real parts is of importance to me.

I did a simulation by randomly generating $300$ permutation matrices (incidentally, sometime not of full rank and that can be dimensionally reduced thus, not the point here). The chart of their Real parts follows.

[image]

None of their real part is lower than $-1$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "is a basis one"

Comment: @Michael Burr Maybe a basis matrix is a permutation matrix ? Can you, Kanak, give some precision ?

Comment: Which means that ma question is likely to be a duplicate of, e.g. this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970702/what-are-the-properties-of-eigenvalues-of-permutation-matrices), isn't it ? Or at least to derive from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the minimum eigenvalue is $-1$, but we can say more than that. The eigenvalues have to lie on the unit circle (and having an argument in $\pi\mathbb Q$)

The reason for this is that a permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles. In matrix terms this means that the matrix is a product of independent (cyclic) rotation matrices that has eigenvalues of $e^{2ik\pi/n}$.